# How to find individual data of a user after listing them out via *ngFor

Tags: angular, observable, httprequest

Im using *ngFor to print individual list items containing my clients data. Each client has its own list item. I'm trying to make each list item clickable to route to a page that shows the clients individual data.

I'm not even sure where to start

```
<ul *ngIf="holdData">
    <li *ngFor="let users of holdData">
        <p class = "name content"> {{ users.name }} </p>
        <p class = "id content"> {{ users.property}} </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you  show the app.module.ts?

Comment: Please read the documentation, you will learn the basics of angular, in this case, specifically routing: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to list down users and on clicking any user you want to route to the page that shows its details.

You have to make use of a router and pass data or id along with the routes:

Pass id then you can catch the id in the new page (where the user is routed), and then make api calls from there to get your user data.

Follow the steps:

Make a new component where you want to display the user details.
In the module where you list down user, add a router file and in your router file add the routes

```
const userRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'user/:id',      component: UserDetailComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class UserRouter {

}
```

In your html file add a function which takes the id of the user selected as an input.

```
<ul *ngIf="holdData">
    <li *ngFor="let users of holdData" (click)="routeTo(user.id)">
        <p class = "name content"> {{ users.name }} </p>
        <p class = "id content"> {{ users.property}} </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In your Ts file write the function, which will navigate to the route:

```
routeTo = (userid:number) => {
  this.router.navigate(['user', { id: userid}]);
}
```

Finally, in your new component's ngOnInit you can take the passed id and do whatever you want to do with it.

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
      this.service.geUser(params.get('id')))
  );
```

Please note: You have to inject/import the required service. The above solution will help you not only in this case, but anywhere where you want to do routing.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of previous answers. If you want to route to another page use the html anchor link. When you present an anchor link, end user will get some extra browser features. Ex. right click the link to open new tab.

```
<ul *ngIf="holdData" class="some-list">
    <li *ngFor="let user of holdData">
        <a routerLink="/userDetails/{{user .id}}">{{ user.name }}</a>
        <div>{{ user.property}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the style the list content with flex-box(using sass)

```
ul.some-list{
   .li{
     display:flex;
     justify-content:space-between;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mixanm)

```
<ul *ngIf="holdData">
    <li *ngFor="let users of holdData; let i=index" (click)=doSomething(i)>
        <p class = "name content"> {{ users.name }} </p>
        <p class = "id content"> {{ users.property}} </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

TS:

```
doSomething(i)
{
  console.log("handle your Data",i);
}
```

Comment: i think OP want to create a new page for each user details as he specified `I'm trying to make each list item clickable to route to a page`

Answer (score 0):

Create a component to show user details.then add routes for that component in your routing module routes array something like

```
{path:'userDetails/:id',componenet:yourComponent}
```

then add `routerlink`  in your html to navigate to new page with user id

```
 <li *ngFor="let users of holdData" routerLink="/userDetails/{{users.id}}">
```

then get the id param from  your route in new component and show the details